# Besides Bitfinex, which crypto currency exchange(s) have Trailing Stop Loss

Tags: exchanges

I was using Bitfinex until they stopped allowing U.S. clients.

They are the only exchange I know that has a **Trailing Stop Loss** feature.

Are there any others?

It's very dangerous to ones portfolio to **trade** cryptos without stop loss functionality if you cannot stay glued to your screen all day long. And a normal stop loss is too rigid to work well in the very volatile crypto environment.

Comment: Please don't create multiple new tags in a single question unless you expect them to be useful in categorizing content in the future.

Comment: bitmex also have trailing stop-loss.

Answer (score 1):

Kraken have the real deal, where one can set stop-loss based on %, but their trading platform has been a bit unreliable lately.

Bistamp also have trailing stop-loss, but very low on selection of coins.

Comment: "but their trading platform has been a bit unreliable lately." Only reason I don't use Kraken.